# How to call a constructor of a constructor inside a parameter?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I need to create an Array with objects from another class but the other class use objects of another class in the constructors too... I will try to explain better:

```
public class BookStore
{
    private String storeName; //e.g. "Jason's New Books"
    private Book[] inventory; // Array of Book objects

    public BookStore()
    {
        inventory = new Book[100];

        inventory[3] = new Book("James Joyce", 2013, "ULYSSES");
    }
```

I need to create this Book Array but I can't figure out how to put the parameters, because in the Book class the constructor is like this:

```
public Book(Author author, Date published, String title)
```

As you can see, this constructor uses objects from another class to initiate, and the other class the constructors are like this:

```
public Date()
```

and

```
public Author()
```

When I try to compile the BookStore class I get the following error:

> "incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to Author"

Comment: `incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to Author` is pretty self explanatory. You need to create an author object first, then pass it instead of a string. Simple version - `Author a = new Author(); new Book(a);`

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
import java.util.Date;

inventory[index] = new Book(
    new Author("Author name"),
    new Date(115, 11, 10), // The 10th of December, 2015
    "book title"
);
```

Considering that the `Author` class has defined such a **constructor**:

```
public class Author {
    private String name;
    // Other member variables

    public Author(String name) {
         this.name = name;
    }

    // Other methods
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only have parameterless constructors in the `Date` and `Author` classes, you'll have to create the instances using multiple statements :

```
Author author = new Author();
author.setName("James Joyce"); // assuming such a method exists
Date date = new Date();
date.setYear(2013); // assuming such a method exists
inventory[3] = new Book(author, date, "ULYSSES");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you just need to create an instance of each object:

```
private Book[] inventory; // Array of Book objects

    public BookStore()
    {
        inventory = new Book[100];
        inventory[3] = new Book(new Author(), new Date(), "title");
```

You could alternatively do something like:

```
        Author author = new Author();
        Date date = new Date();

        inventory[3] = new Book(author, title, "title");
```

You will need to pass in the required parameters for each object to match your constructor

Answer (score 1):

Since your **Book** class constructer `Book(Author author, Date published, String title)` accepts 3 parameters  as following

1. First parameter is object of **Author** class
2. Second parameter is object of **Date**
3. Third parameter is String variable

And you are using String, so its throughing that error

Hence, instead of using

```
inventory[3] = new Book("James Joyce", 2013, "ULYSSES");
```

Use

```
Author objAuthor = new Author();
Date objDate = new Date();
inventory[3] = new Book(objAuthor, objDate, "ULYSSES");
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Sparta has one problem: the month number in java.util.Date is zero-based (January is 0, February is 1, etc) and wraps around, and the year is 1900-based, so `new Date(2015, 12, 10)` is not the "10th of December, 2015" but "10th of January 3916"

Sorry, would have liked to comment on your answer but I do not yet have enough reputation...